# Sens de l'expression « Seulement, il y a eu le soupçon et c'est toujours cela de gagné. »

Tags: sens, traduction

Je suis en train de lire « La Peste » d'Albert Camus, et sur la 2ème page il dit :

> Seulement, il y a eu le soupçon et c'est toujours cela de gagné.

Je ne comprends pas ce que cela veut dire. Surtout, je ne comprends pas le mot « soupçon », parce que le dictionnaire dit que ça veut dire « suspicion », mais alors, je ne sais pas si ça veut dire une autre chose dans ce contexte.

Plus tôt, il dit

> Mais il est des villes et des pays où les gens ont, de temps en temps, le soupçon d'autre chose.

et plus tard il dit

> Oran est apparemment une ville sans soupçons.

Pourriez-vous m'expliquer cette expression ? Et peut-être la traduire en anglais ou en espagnol ?

Comment: In English, if you have a *suspicion*, it is generally about something negative; this is not the case in French for *soupçon*. The English translation, *The Plague,* uses the word *intimation,* which is a better choice (*hint* might also work). I don't know whether this addresses your question, though

Comment: @PeterShor It *is* also the case in French for "soupçon"; in the TLFi only "A2" out of the two groups, "A1" and "A2", shows uses that do not involve something negative, and thoses senses are not used very often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the whole paragraph.

*On dira sans doute que cela n’est pas particulier à notre
ville et qu’en somme tous nos contemporains sont ainsi. Sans
doute, rien n’est plus naturel, aujourd’hui, que de voir des gens
travailler du matin au soir et choisir ensuite de perdre aux
cartes, au café, et en bavardages, le temps qui leur reste pour
vivre. Mais il est des villes et des pays où les gens ont, de temps
en temps, le soupçon d’autre chose. En général, cela ne change
pas leur vie. Seulement, il y a eu le soupçon et c’est toujours cela
de gagné. Oran, au contraire, est apparemment une ville sans
soupçons, c’est-à-dire une ville tout à fait moderne. Il n’est pas
nécessaire, en conséquence, de préciser la façon dont on s’aime
chez nous. Les hommes et les femmes, ou bien se dévorent rapidement dans ce qu’on appelle l’acte d’amour, ou bien
s’engagent dans une longue habitude à deux. Entre ces extrêmes, il n’y a pas souvent de milieu. Cela non plus n’est pas
original. À Oran comme ailleurs, faute de temps et de réflexion,
on est bien obligé de s’aimer sans le savoir.*

"Avoir soupçon de qqc" means "to suspect sth", this verb having the particular sense of

> "to have an idea that something is probably true or likely to happen, especially something bad, but without having definite proof" ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/suspect_1?q=suspect)).

There is no context for something bad here, it is the opposite. What is being suspected is another life, a greater life.

However, the author is using an article (avoir *le* soupçon de qqc) and that is no clear, but there is no other explanation.

*Seulement, il y a eu le soupçon et c'est toujours cela de gagné.* — This means that even though most people that are able to suspect they could have a better existence do not achieve anything in the way of making for themselves a better life, they still have the opportunity to dream of the possibility, and in doing so they better themselves so to speak in the contemplation of this utopic vision, although this trifle of an achievement, as we might call it, is hardly a consolation ; nevertheless (seulement)  they earn ("gagné") that ("cela") for themselves.

*translation* —  However there has been that inkling and that much at least has been made theirs.

*Oran est apparemment une ville sans soupçons.* — In this sentence "soupçon" is used representatively to refer to the type of assumptions referred to previously by means of the expression "avoir soupçon de qqc". It means that there are not in Oran any  dreamers of the type the author just mentioned. The city ("Oran") has been put for "the people of Oran" and "ville" stands for "its people".

Comment: Excellente explication. A rapprocher de la définition : *Simple conjecture, avis, hypothèse ou **intuition** concernant quelque chose sans connotation défavorable.* https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/soup%C3%A7on

Comment: C'est plus facile à comprendre avec le paragraphe complet, car cet usage de "soupçon" n'est pas (plus?) courant.

Comment: @XouDo Je crois que "soupçon" en tant que "quantité minime" est beaucoup plus courant; personnellement je ne saisis pas bien la différence, ce qui signifie que « soupçon » avec ce sens « positif » n'est pas souvent utilisé.  Pour moi la connotation « négative » demeure et  à mon avis un autre terme aurait été plus heureux dans ce paragraphe (qui soit dit en passant est une petite merveille  toujours bonne à relire).

Comment: Le choix de ce terme justement vient peut-être du fait que ce "soupçon" dans le contexte reste négatif du point de vue de la société (je dirais même suspect voire subversif!), même s'il est plutôt positif pour les individus, du point de vue du narrateur.

Comment: @XouDo L'idée va chercher loin, mais pourquoi pas ? Un soupçon d'insinuation d'un vice caché de la société !